# How do you find the length of a SQLWCHAR?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

It's really annoying.  In general, these strings seem to be hard to work with.

I've can do this:

```
 std::wstring strdsn = L"stringsaidtwice";
 SQLWCHAR DSName[60] = L"stringsaidtwice";

 retcode = SQLConnect(connHandle, DSName, strdsn.length(), NULL,
    0, NULL, 0);
```

This does NOT work:

```
 sizeof(DSName);
 sizeof(DSName)*sizeof(SQLWCHAR);
```

Maybe trim it and then sizeof() ?

Ugh.  Obviously not the right thing to do.  But basic operations like sizing, copying from 'normal' strings seem really evasive with SQLWCHARs.

NOTE:  ODBC seems to be the 'new' game as MS is dumping OLE DB and EF is slow. (as of June 2014).

UPDATE:  OK, here are the basic tools needed to be able to function with SQLWCHARS

```
    // To convert an ordinary string to a SQLWCHAR
    char  regcstring[120] = "mystringinput";  //regular char * input
    const size_t WCHARBUFSIZE = 120;
    SQLWCHAR  DSName[WCHARBUFSIZE];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, regcstring, -1, DSName, WCHARBUFSIZE);

    // To provide the size of a SQLWCHAR (wchar_t)
retcode = SQLConnect(connHandle, DSName, std::wcslen(DSName), NULL,
    0, NULL, 0);
```

Well, this is helpful to me, at least.....

Comment: At a guess, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SQLWCHAR` is supposed to work the same way as standard wide strings, you can use the [standard wide string C functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide) such as `wcsncpy` and `wcslen`. Of course I would recommend doing what you can with the `std::wstring` before resorting to the C functions. I'm also half expecting someone who actually has experience using `SQLWCHAR` to know of something better, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I've added a few things.  Main issues I had was populating them from ordinary strings (or char *), and finding length.  Anyway, thanks for your help.